# Multiple -a with greater than / less than break bash script

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, comparison-operators

I wrote a bash script that performs a curl call only during business hours.  For some reason, the hourly comparison fails when I add an "-a" operator (and for some reason my bash does not recognize "&&").

Though the script is much larger, here is the relevant piece:

```
HOUR=`date +%k`

if [ $HOUR > 7 -a $HOUR < 17 ];
then
  //do sync
fi
```

The script gives me the error:

```
./tracksync: (last line): Cannot open (line number): No such file
```

However, this comparison does not fail:

```
if [ $DAY != "SUNDAY" -a $HOUR > 7 ];
then
  //do sync
fi
```

Is my syntax wrong or is this a problem with my bash?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot use `<` and `>` in bash scripts as such. Use `-lt` and `-gt` for that:

```
if [ $HOUR -gt 7 -a $HOUR -lt 17 ]
```

`<` and `>` are used by the shell to perform redirection of stdin or stdout.

The comparison that you say is working is actually creating a file named `7` in the current directory.

As for `&&`, that also has a special meaning for the shell and is used for creating an "AND list" of commands.

The best documentation for all these: `man bash` (and `man test` for details on comparison operators)

Comment: Actually, you can use `<` and `>` in `[ ]`, but you need to escape or quote them to keep them from being interpreted as redirects, and they do alphabetic string comparisons, rather than numeric comparisons.  For example, `[ 7 \> 17 ]` is true, because "7" is alphabetically after ("greater than") "17".

Answer (score 6):

There are a few answers here but none of them recommend actual numerical context.

Here is how to do it in bash:

```
if (( hour > 7 && hour < 17 )); then
   ...
fi
```

Note that "$" is not needed to expand variables in numerical context.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go.  Image using universal math symbols for comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use quotes around variable references and "standard" operators:

```
if [ "$HOUR" -gt 7 -a "$HOUR" -lt 17 ]; ...; fi
```

Comment: If I know there won't be spaces or special characters, is there any reason to do this?

Comment: Robustness (there is no guarantee that the *date* command will behave as you expect), and making it a habit.

Comment: Even better in bash is to use [[ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[[` instead, because it is safer and has more features. Also use `-gt` and `-lt` for numeric comparison.

```
if [[ $HOUR -gt 7 && $HOUR -lt 17 ]]
then
    # do something
fi
```

Comment: @Calvin Froedge: that means your script isn't running in bash; if you want to use bash extensions like `[[`, you need to start it with  `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`